# I can't find examples or documentation about ASP.NET Core accessing Google API's using OAuth2 Authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, google-oauth

I've read the documentation (poor in .NET Core) and the only examples I found are how to implement OAuth2 from Google with Identity.
But what I need is to use Google API's (any example with any API will help) authenticating with OAuth2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oauth2 login to Google api with ASP .net core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942102/oauth2-login-to-google-api-with-asp-net-core-mvc)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have tried this and didn't worked for me. The code is incomplete or at least needs more knowledge than mine.